# Was Seska's character arc planned from the beginning?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Between Seasons 1 and 2 of *Voyager*, there is a dramatic change in the character of Seska:

> [image][image]

In particular, she

> becomes a villain.

Seska appears in a number of Season 1 episodes prior to the 12th episode, ["State of Flux"](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/110.htm), where we find out that she is not as she seems.

**Was this development in Seska's character part of the planning of the series itself?  Or did the writers only conceive of it when writing "State of Flux?"**

Comment: I'm seeing a Bajoran on the left and a Cardassian on the right... how are they supposed to be the same person?

Comment: @RedCaio : That's the "dramatic change" I'm referring to.  Seska is actually a Cardassian spy, initially posing as a Bajoran.

Comment: oh, so you're asking if that was a retcon or not. gotcha, thanks :)

Comment: @Praxis: If we agree that the photos in the question should remain in spoiler tags, it makes sense to move the text from your comment there, too, and remove the (non-spoiler-protected) comment.

Comment: She acts pretty sketchy early on in seasson one she is encouraging belana to disobey orders

Comment: @Himarm : Definitely.  I've found authoritative confirmation (see below).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes, it was planned from the beginning.

[image]

According to p.143 of [***Captains' Logs Supplemental: The Unauthorized Guide to the New Trek Voyages***](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0316329207) by Edward Gross and Mark Altman, the episode was planned during the early development stages of *Voyager*, and quotes Executive Producer Jeri Taylor as saying,

> *"State of Flux" was one of the first [stories] that we bought."*

Comment: I don't usually answer my own questions, but I found this resource (of which I was previously unaware) in the process of researching someone else's question, and it happened to have the answer. :-)

Comment: Interesting. The quote I read on Memory Alpha (which seems to be from Star Trek Voyager Magazine) suggests that the actress was cast with an eye to making her a villain, but with no mention of her being a Cardassian, just a disgruntled Maquis.